# Responsive Nav with flexbox-wrap

Tags: javascript, html, css

I found a lot of guides and samples of responsive navbars but I haven't found one which fits my problem. I would like to build some kind of dynamically responsive nav. The goal is that if the navbar shrinks the items should dynamically move to the mobile nav. So if space is not enough to show all items, it should show hide one and display that in the mobile nav. I am stuck in this case. I built a test navbar with jsfiddle to visualize my approach. https://jsfiddle.net/ms6L8c2n/

```
<html>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="NavLeft">
          <img src="https://www.google.de/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width=130 height=40>
          <a>Home</a>
          <a>First Link</a>
          <a>Second Link</a>
          <a>Home</a>
          <a>First Link</a>
          <a>Second Link</a>
        </div>
        <div class="NavRight">
          <a>Account</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}

img{
  margin-right: 50px;
}

a{
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  font-family: Helvetica
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline
}

.navbar {
  background: #22292f;
  padding:0  100px ;
}

.container{
  margin: auto;
  max-width:1200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.NavLeft{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 40px;
}
.NavRight{
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: "The goal is that if the navbar shrinks the items should dynamically move to the mobile nav". where/what is the mobile nav? Please elaborate your question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my example now. I would like to accomplish two things now.
1st: Only show the burger symbol if one link of my navbar is hidden.
2nd: Only show hidden links of the navbar in my mobile menu. 

Example: If I shrink my screen and one element of the navbar is hidden I would like to display the burger icon and in the mobile menu only the ony element which is not displayed in the main navbar.
https://jsfiddle.net/ms6L8c2n/47/